# In tmux can I resize a pane to an absolute value

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to tell tmux to "resize a pane to 5 lines high"?

I know I can do `resize-pane -U 3` to move the dividing line, but sometimes when logging in with a different size monitor the size has changed by a lot of lines that I can't judge by eye.  I'd like to be able to have one command that will change one window to exactly the right number of lines rather than faffing about with multiple `resize-pane` commands.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

> usage: resize-pane [-DLRUZ] [-x width] [-y height] [-t target-pane]
>   [adjustment]

ie.

> resize-pane -t 1 **-y 5**

Comment: The `-x` and `-y` options for `resize-pane` were introduced in *tmux* 1.8.

Comment: This doesn't work using tmux 1.9  It resizes but not to the correct value.  My conf:



`set -g default-terminal "screen"`
new
splitw -v
selectp -t 0
resize-pane -t 0 -y 5
set -g status off

Its almost like tmux has a minimum value or something for auto setting the rows during load.

Comment: just ignore the above.  i can't believe how difficult it is to to write a simple thing on stack overflow.

Comment: Found a great summary here: https://michaelsoolee.com/resize-tmux-panes/, which says the same thing, but I find that giving a real example instead of documented example is easier to digest - i.e. `:resize-pane -D 10` (Resizes the current pane down by 10 cells). Change `D` to `L`, `R`, `U` as explained above.

Comment: Also not working for me in tmux 2.6. The pane will not resize below some minimum value (around 20 lines).

Answer (score 186):

What about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> then (pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) + arrow?

If in `tmux < 1.8`, doing this by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> then (<kbd>Esc</kbd> + arrow) * `n`, where `n` is the number of times you want to resize.

Comment: That does `resize-pane -U 1` (or -D ...) which is what I mention in the question. So I know I can do this, and it does work, but I wanted a single command I could map and then reset the size easily.

Comment: Esc + arrow keys work for me. Don't like the fact that there are too many keystrokes though.

Comment: I didn't like that either, so added "bind-key J resize-pane -D 5" and "bind-key K resize-pane -U 5" and can resize by pressing J and K

Comment: Life saver, thank you, I saw searching for this Ctrl+B and keeping Ctrl with arrow to move pane.

Answer (score 149):

In tmux 1.8, the size of the panes may be adjusted interactively. Under the default key bindings this may be done by the prefix key (C-b) followed by the meta key combined with arrow keys (M-arrow), where arrow is one of the up/down/left/right arrow keys.

E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> will adjust the size upwards.

Note that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key may be held down while the up/down/left/right keys are pressed multiple times to make multiple adjustments.

E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> will adjust the size upwards by two movements and left by one movement.

Comment: On Mac that just alternates between the windows.

Comment: This works on Mac, @JackHasaKeyboard. Don't forget the `Alt` key.

Comment: holding down alt doesn't work for multiple resizes. On v1.8, centos. Not much better than typing `resize-panel`

Comment: On Mac it worked for me using `Esc` instead of `Alt`

Answer (score 0):

while pressing your bind key dont release your fingers and user the narrwors U D L R to resize your pan. 
BindKey + R to resize to the right side.

Comment: This question is about setting an absolute position, not making a relative adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, it'd have to be `<Prefix>` + `H/J/K/L` on Tmux 1.8+. The arrow keys didn't work for me.