# Any way to adjust tmux panes to inequal percentages?

Tags: terminal, tmux

When I only have 2 panes, adjusting their height or width (depending on a vertical or horizontal split) is simple but what I'm specifically looking for is when you have 4 panes, is it possible to make one not share its height (or width) with its adjacent pane?

Using the usual resize commands/keystrokes will not adjust only the active pane. For example, if I want to make the bottom left pane taller, shrinking the top left pane, both bottom panes will grow and both top panes will shrink.

What I want is for pane 0 (top left) to take about 25% height while pane 1 (top right) retains the 50% height leaving pane 2 (bottom left) with 75% height and pane 3 (bottom right) with 50% height.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

To expand on this, here is a a quickly put together image of what I am trying to achieve.

[tmux Panes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi2kW.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In tmux can I resize a pane to an absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145078/in-tmux-can-i-resize-a-pane-to-an-absolute-value)

Comment: That does not answer my question, no. That will change the whole line, not just the one pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you show in the picture is possible. Just make the vertical split first.

```
Prefix+%
Prefix+"
```

Then switch to the third pane and

```
Prefix+"
```

Now you can adjust your pane sizes as necessary.

Your title doesn't really match the picture you show. A pane's border has to be straight. You **cannot** have something like this:

```
_________________
|      |         |
|      |         |
|      |_________|
|        |       |
|________|       |
|        |       |
|        |       |
------------------
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was as simple as just creating the vertical split first. I've also tried it with doing the horizontal split first and that allows me to move the left/right border of each separately.